# how to get $_productCollection in phtml file magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, list.phtml

I am new to Magneto, I want to create HoverSlider on product list page. I want to override list.phtml file in my module. I am getting error in accessing methods of `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct`.

**Catalog_category_view.xml**

```
<head>
    <link src="Ktpl_HoverSlider::js/hoverslider.js"/>
    <link src="Ktpl_HoverSlider::css/hoverslider.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Ktpl_HoverSlider::product/list.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

**list.phtml**

```
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();

$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
```

Comment: Share you complete code here, what you've tried

Comment: I added code of layout and list.phtml which is in my module.

Comment: i donot think your  list.phtml template class is  not `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct`

Answer (score -1):

Hi please try below code

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory'); 
$collection = $productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection ->addAttributeToSelect('*')


foreach ($collection as $product) {

    echo "<br/>";
    echo $product->getId().'==='.$product->getName().'==='.$product->getTypeId().'==='.$product->getSku().'===';
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: as well you can add query as per you need thanks

Comment: Using object manager directly in a phtml file is not a good approach.

Comment: @Sumit ok then when we need to make plugin how we can get some data or something else is there any ways?

Comment: You can create Block class and call the product collection there. Call the block function in your phtml file.

Comment: @Sumit so in block file can I use object manager or not?

Comment: You can inject the class for example, \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory in your block class instead of calling it with objectManager.